# Is it possible to open up an application from another application from simply entering its app's name?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm making a little project in which i would enter a code-name, for example, "A" for Facebook. I would like it to open up the Facebook app when i enter "A" in the edittext area. How can i do this? I know there's a way to give it a package name and then open it up using an intent, but that seems really inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

It's prety easy, declare the editText then get the text in it and if it equals to what ever you want then make an intent that opens the app.

```
EditText type = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
String xx = type.getText.toString();

if (xx == "A"){
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
} else{

}
```

or you can use this method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

but I recomment the first one because you may not know the mainActivity's name of the app.

Comment: Sorry, im very new, but how would i know what the package name is for Facebook?

Comment: It's okay, I'm not sure how by android. But when I needed it I used google play to get it. this is it"com.facebook.katana"